# How to populate a spinner with the result of a Firestore query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

I am creating a `spinner` which will show the subject name. The subject names are stored in my Firestore database as follows:

```
subjects (collection)
|
|--- SUB01 (document)
|    |
|    |--- name : "Android"
|
|--- SUB02
|    |
|    |--- name : "Java"
```

I could fetch the result to an `RecyclerView` but unable to help myself to do so for spinner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference subjectsRef = rootRef.collection("subjects");
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjects);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
subjectsRefRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                String subject = document.getString("name");
                subjects.add(subject);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

The result will be a spinner that will contain 2 items:

```
Android
Java
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks