# how to get the assign the queried value to global variable?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

the code is to record the total no. of users in a particular society

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
export const new_reg = functions.firestore
    .document('mobile/{mobile}')
    .onCreate((change, context) =>{
        const society:String = change.get("society")
        let value = 1
        admin.firestore().doc(`society/${society}`).get()
        .then((userSnapshot: { data: () => { (): any; new(): any; users: number; }; }) => {
            value = userSnapshot.data().users
            console.log(value)
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            console.log(error)    
        })
        ++value
        console.log(value)
        return null
    })
```

the value of "value" does not get updated with code from line 16 to 24.

note:- line 18 is just to confirm the value that is getting picked up by the code.

the value logged on the console by line 18 is always the right value

the value that gets incremented in the line 24 is the value i initially declared and not the one i retrieved from firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` returns immediately with a promise.  So do `then` and `catch`.  They asynchronous, and the callbacks are invoked some time later with the results of the query.  Your code will not wait for the query to finish - it will keep going and increment value before the query is finished.

With Cloud Functions background triggers, you are [obliged to return a promise that resolves when all of the asynchronous work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  Right now, you are returning null, which won't work at all.  You should instead return the promise from the chain starting with `get()`.

```
return admin.firestore().doc(`society/${society}`).get()
    .then(...)
    .catch(...)
```

It's not clear to me why you need to work with `value`, but in any case, you'll need to deal with promises correctly.

Comment: it work on ```value``` and creates several other documents which are stored in various location with various other data.

Comment: OK, you'll still have to work with promises correctly.

Comment: can anyone ans the following question too

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61550428/how-to-add-data-from-firestore-to-my-spinner